# Как сериализовать часть XML файла

Tags: c#, xml, .net, сериализация

Делаю вот так

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(_pathFileSettings);
var xmlWriter = xmlDoc.Root.Element("EmulatorsSettings").CreateWriter();

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<EmulatorSensorSettings>));
var emulator = this.EmulatorSensorSettingsList.Select(p => 
                                             p.EmulatorSensorSettings).ToList();
ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, emulator);
```

но он ругается на "WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мн кажется, что одним из вариантов будет сериализовать в отдельный чистый xml-стрим, а потом смержить с существующим xml в нужную ноду.

[На StackOverflow это обсуждалось, что-то похожее.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190079/combine-a-serialized-object-with-an-existing-xml-doc-and-return-it)